# Can't access object attribute

Tags: c++, object, reference

I have a problem with an object function.

I have an object with a map as an attribute:

```
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "../stopwords/stopwords.h"
#include "../porter/porter.h"

class Parser{

private:
    unsigned int cant_documentos;
    unsigned int cant_terminos;
    std::map<std::string,short> dicc_stopwords;
    std::map<std::string,unsigned int> hash_frecuencias_globales;
    std::map<std::string,std::map<std::string,unsigned int> >hash_frecuencias_locales;
    std::map<std::string,std::string> hash_apariciones_unicas;
public:
    Parser();

public:
    void destroy();

public:     

    void agregar_termino_a_hash(std::string termino,std::string nombre_archivo);
public:

    void cargar_terminos(std::string linea,std::string nombre_archivo);

};

#endif //PARSER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "parser.h"
#include <string.h>

using std::map;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ofstream;

void Parser::agregar_termino_a_hash(string termino,string nombre_archivo){

unsigned int size = termino.size();

if(dicc_stopwords[termino] == 1) return; //No entra porque es un stopword

unsigned int ultimo_char = stem((char*)termino.c_str(),0,size-1); 

termino = termino.substr(0,ultimo_char+1);

if(!((*hash_frecuencias_locales)[termino])){
    hash_frecuencias_locales[termino] = 1;
    if(hash_frecuencias_globales[termino]){
        (*hash_apariciones_unicas).erase(termino);
        hash_frecuencias_globales[termino]++;
    }
    else{
        cant_terminos++;
        hash_frecuencias_globales[termino] = 1;
        (*hash_apariciones_unicas)[termino] = nombre_archivo;
    }
}else
    hash_frecuencias_locales[termino]++;
}
```

But I keep getting errors like these:

no ‘operator++(int)’ declared for postfix ‘++’

Or something like:

no match for ‘operator!’ in...

Comment: Please, post the real error descriptions. Also - do you have `#include <map>`? And there's a missing `;` after the class declaration - this causes somtimes strange error messages.

Comment: Please show the exact code, without the "do something" part and with all the relevant declarations.

Comment: Post the code, as described, it should work. http://ideone.com/5zpYVH

Answer (score 0):

This lines will never work

```
if(!((*hash_frecuencias_locales)[termino])){
  hash_frecuencias_locales[termino] = 1;
```

with this definition:

```
std::map<std::string,std::map<std::string,unsigned int> >hash_frecuencias_locales;
```

My compiler agrees with me (after some cleaning in your file...)

```
$ g++ test_map_pb.cpp
test_map_pb.cpp: In member function ‘void Parser::agregar_termino_a_hash(std::string, std::string)’:
test_map_pb.cpp:63:64: erreur: ‘stem’ was not declared in this scope
 unsigned int ultimo_char = stem((char*)termino.c_str(),0,size-1);
                                                                ^
test_map_pb.cpp:68:7: erreur: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int> >’)
 if(!((*hash_frecuencias_locales)[termino])){
       ^
test_map_pb.cpp:69:39: erreur: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int> >::mapped_type {aka std::map<std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>}’ and ‘int’)
```

Try to do a minimal example and you'll see that your problem wasn't where you thought.

Comment: you are right! i didn't modify that! (the code was copied from a previous vertion)